# PHP add values from multidimensional array into one array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array `$array` like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 11 
        [name] => scifi 
        ) 
    [1] => Array (
         [id] => 12 
         [name] => documetary 
     ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 10 
        [name] => comedy 
    ) 
)
```

How could I turn it into simply:

`Array ( 11, 12, 10 )` with no key value pairs.

I am trying to extract only the `id` from each array and add them into 1 array. I am trying it with a foreach;

```
$ids = [];

if ( $array ) {
  foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    $ids[] = $term->id;
  }
}

print_r($ids);
```

It just returns 3 empty arrays `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: You don't need to loop yourself, you can just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: @CBroe thanks that is a cool function! but it still returns more arrays `Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 12 [2] => 10 ) ` instead just the ids in 1 array. Now i should loop over that?

Comment: you seem to be confused, `array_column()` returns ONE array with three key-value pairs - i.e. result as expected _the ids in 1 array_.

Comment: @berend i am trying to get an array with the ids without the keys

Comment: an array will [always](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) have 1 or more key-value pairs. maybe you actually need a string: `"11, 12, 10"`? or an array with one key-value pair: `[0] => "11, 12, 10"`?

Comment: `$array = array_column($array, 'id');` or `$string = implode(', ', array_column($array, 'id'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop, you can do this:

```
$arr1 = [
 ['id'=>11,'name'=>'scifi'],
 ['id'=>12,'name'=>'documentry'],
 ['id'=>10,'name'=>'comedy'],
];

$arr2 = [];
foreach($arr1 as $internal){
  array_push($arr2,$internal['id']);
}

print_r($arr2);
```

Here we access all internal array's ID's and insert them into a new array.